# Import-Module PoshRSJob with Executionpolicy RemoteSigned

Tags: powershell

I downloaded the [PoshRSJob](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob) module. When I try to import the module it always throws the following error (translated from German):

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ipmo "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PoshRSJob"
ipmo : The File "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PoshRSJob\Scripts\TabExpansion.ps1" could not be loaded. The File "C:\Program
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PoshRSJob\Scripts\TabExpansion.ps1" is not signed digitally. You can't execute this script on your system. More information: "about_Execution_Policies" unter
"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170"..
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ ipmo "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PoshRSJob"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : Sicherheitsfehler: (:) [Import-Module], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Our ExecutionPolicy is RemoteSigned

Is there a way to get this module working in a RemoteSigned environment, without Bypassing the Executionpolicy everytime I use the Module in a Script, and without setting the ExecutionPolicy to Unrestricted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that Windows is treating the files as remote files despite being on your machine locally. Sometimes Windows will know when files have come from the internet (for example if you download through IE or Edge instead of say, Firefox). Behind the scenes, this is storing zone information in an alternate data stream associated with the file, but that can be modified or stripped off.

Right click the PSD1, PS1, PSM1 files inside the module and choose "Properties" and if there's an unblock option, make sure it's unticked.

Alternatively you could run the cmdlet [Unblock-File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file) if you have PowerShell 5.1 or greater.