# Set-ExecutionPolicy for one instance

Tags: powershell, import-module, executionpolicy

Here's the problem: I'm trying to import the PoshRSJob module to my session of PowerShell. In order to do that I need to bypass my execution policy (remotesigned). I've tried this line:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

But it throws this error:

> Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is 
>   overridden by a policy defined at a more specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its 
>   current effective execution policy of RemoteSigned.

I only want this to persist for the current session that is open, but I can't get it to work in any capacity. I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42768102/import-module-poshrsjob-with-executionpolicy-remotesigned) question, but it did not resolve the issue. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Do you have administrative privileges on your box?  It looks like a GPO is overriding you.

Comment: I'm the administrator for my computer. I tried running it in an elevated PowerShell session and it still failed.

Comment: After you run the command, what is in `$env:PSExecutionPolicyPreference`?  Did you try `-Force`?

Comment: It returns: Bypass

Comment: Are you trying to import or install the module?

Comment: It seems that somewhere along the line, the problem was resolved. I'm not exactly sure why or where though.